# Reading only 1 file using Apache Camel in his context life cycle

Tags: file, apache-camel

Reading only 1 file in the camel context life cycle (1 file per camel context)
maxMessagesPerPoll of file property is not working while giving it as 1

I have tried maxMessagesPerPoll=1 in the configure method of Route Builder, but it is not working.

I have also tried using method setDurationMaxMessages(1) of the main class of apache camel, (docs says that it sets the duration of the maximum number of messages that the application will process before terminating) but the problem in this approach, the context is not getting stopped. Even though I tried using setDurationIdle(1) but that also is not stopping the context (it was working in other scenarios), so operation is not getting performed.

```
CamelContext ctx = new DefaultCamelContext();

Main camel = new Main();

camel.addRouteBuilder(new MyRouteBuilder());

camel.setDurationMaxMessages(1);

camel.setDurationIdle(1);

camel.run();
```

The expected result is to use the apache camel to process the only file.

The actual result is it is processing all the files in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Okay there may be a little bug in Apache Camel, I am checking this and have logged a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13556

Comment: Thanks for the response Claus.
So is there any other way through which I can implement the use case? We are blocked right now, a need a way to implement ths

Comment: Something along a timer with pollenrich: from timer?repeatCount=1 -> pollEnrich file w/ timeout = 1000 -> to

Comment: Regarding the bug open, it is resolved with the version 3.0.0, 3.0.0-M3.
So, when can we expect the version in the maven as our project is dependent on that. One guy in the gitter told that 3.0.0-M3 version will be available in two weeks. Can you tell more on this, it will be very helpful.
Thanks in advance.